# repetir valores de un rango dado por dos columnas de un data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Dada una tabla como esta:

```
L   r_a r_b A
A   0   2   xs
A   3   6   m
C   7   9   l
B   10  11  xl
```

Me gustaria en vez de tener dos columnas que agrupen el rango(r_a indica el principio del rango de valores y r_b el final del rango), tener una fila por cada valor. Es decir que se generara una tabla como esta:

```
L   r_a A
A   0   xs
A   1   xs
A   2   xs
A   3   m
A   4   m
A   5   m
A   6   m
C   7   l
C   8   l
C   9   l
B   10  xl
B   11  xl
```

Como se ve los valores de la columna L y A, se mantienen dependiendo del rango donde se encontraba.

Yo lo que probé fue primero calcular el rango en otra columna mediante:

df1['range'] = df1['r_b']  - df1['r_a']

Y a continuación amplié el dataframe mediante:

pd.DataFrame(df1.values.repeat(df1.range, axis=0),columns=df1.columns,).astype(df1.dtypes).

La cosa es que claro me copia X veces la misma linea, y no tengo claro como poder cambiar el valor de la columna r_a.

```
L   r_a  r_b  A
A   0    2    xs
A   0    2    xs
A   0    2    xs
A   3    6    m
A   3    6    m
A   3    6    m
A   3    6    m
C   7    9    l
C   7    9    l
C   7    9    l
B   10   11   xl
B   10   11   xl
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y que intentaste para lograrlo? Por favor lee [como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Podrías usar la función `range`, para algo te ha de servir :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si es la forma más rapida, ya que usa bucle for (no encontré otra forma de lograrlo) y soy nuevo en Pandas. Sin embargo, estas soluciones podrían serte util.

#### Forma 1: Teniendo en cuenta que los rangos podrían no ser consecutivos.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["A", 0, 2, "xs"],
                   ["A", 3, 6, "m"],
                   ["C", 7, 9, "l"],
                   ["B", 10, 11, "xl"]],
                  columns=("L", "r_a", "r_b", "A"))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(((L, i, A) for _, (L, r_a, r_b, A) in df.iterrows() for i in range(r_a, r_b+1)), columns=("L", "r", "A"))
    
print(new_df)
```

La idea sería crear un nuevo DataFrame usando un [generador](https://ellibrodepython.com/yield-python) (creado usando [comprensión de generadores](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/)) en el cual recorremos cada fila del DataFrame original, [desempaquetamos](https://pharos.sh/unpacking-en-python-mas-alla-de-la-asignacion-paralela) lo devuelto por iterrows, que será una tupla del estilo `(index, (valor de la columna 1, valor de la columna 2, ..., valor de la columna n))`. Creamos un rango que va desde `r_a` a `r_b` (inclusive) e iteramos también sobre ese rango. Finalmente, devolvemos una tupla que luego usará el constructor del DataFrame para crear cada registro.

Esto produce:

```
    L   r   A
0   A   0  xs
1   A   1  xs
2   A   2  xs
3   A   3   m
4   A   4   m
5   A   5   m
6   A   6   m
7   C   7   l
8   C   8   l
9   C   9   l
10  B  10  xl
11  B  11  xl
```

#### Forma 2: Asumiendo que los rangos son consecutivos.

Sin embargo, si los rangos con los que trabajas siempre son consecutivos es decir: "`1 a 3`, `4 a 7`, `8 a 20`...", podrías utilizar una forma que quizá sea más rapida y hasta más sencilla.

Basandonos en tu intento de resolver el problema...

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 0, 2, "xs"],
                   ["A", 3, 6, "m"],
                   ["C", 7, 9, "l"],
                   ["B", 10, 11, "xl"]],
                  columns=("L", "r_a", "r_b", "A"))

# Obtenemos el primer valor de la columna r_a
start = df1["r_a"][0]

# recreamos el DataFrame pero con los valores repetidos
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.repeat(df1.r_b - df1.r_a + 1, axis=0),columns=df1.columns).astype(df1.dtypes)

# eliminamos las columnas r_a y r_b
del new_df["r_a"]
del new_df["r_b"]

# Insertamos una columna en la segunda posición llamada r
# y crearemos un rango que vaya de start hasta start + el largo del dataframe (NO inclusive)
new_df.insert(1, "r", range(start, start + len(new_df)))

print(new_df)
```

Produce:

```
    L   r   A
0   A   0  xs
1   A   1  xs
2   A   2  xs
3   A   3   m
4   A   4   m
5   A   5   m
6   A   6   m
7   C   7   l
8   C   8   l
9   C   9   l
10  B  10  xl
11  B  11  xl
```

Comment: Perfecto!! si he tenido que usar la primera opción porque no siempre son consecutivos, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada compañero c: